# How to detect if user tap on "Don't Allow" on Apple's push notification confirmation alert

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I want to fire some event if user taps on "Don't Allow" button on the apple's push notification alert message. Is there any notification getting fired or any other way to detect this action from the user?

Comment: what kind of service do you accessing?

Comment: Push/Remote notifications.

Answer (score 14):

I'm sure someone will need a solid and simple answer to this (like I once did) -- so here you go. Directly after calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];` you can use `NSNotificationCenter` beautifully like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
                                                  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
                                                      //user tapped "Allow"
                                                  }
                                                  else{
                                                      //user tapped "Don't Allow"
                                                  }
                                              }];
```

**NOTE:** My device is currently running iOS 9.2, my Xcode is version 7.2, and my Deployment Target is 8.0.

Comment: I am sure it will work but I still feel its kind of hack :(

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I do't thing so that we can detect what `UIAlertView` button user pressed as there is no any kind of callback methods or delegate etc provided in iOS.

Only if you pressed `Don't Allow` this will disable the push notification service for that particular iOS App and if YES then enable.

And After that through the code we can check and ensure about it using.

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
   // NONE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for some way to detect "Don't Allow" button tap event.

Comment: @sanjana You cannot detect the Don't Allow event but you can use the above code to do something based on your app not being allowed to receive APNs.

Answer (score 0):

```
iOS8 comes with rregisterUserNotificationSettings: delegate method. Using this method we can do some patches.Please review them and Let us know your comments.Please these is only work with iOS8.
```

=> Add/Register Notification.

```
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    }
```

=> **Here Below method is called After Alert Notification Fire. Using Any of the Button Action(Don't allow or Allow) we force fully register Notification. and Dow with some patch Here.**

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

=>We do some trick here

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    NSLog(@"devToken: %@",devToken);

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    NSString* deviceToken = [[[[[devToken description]
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] retain];

    NSLog(@"deviceToken : %@",deviceToken);

    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if((![[standardDefaults valueForKey:@"DeviceToken"] isEqualToString:deviceToken]) || [standardDefaults valueForKey:@"DeviceToken"]==nil){
        [self sendProviderDeviceToken:deviceToken];
    }else{
        //Do Some Stuff Here
    }
}
```